# Choice under Uncertainty: Relation between the certainty equivalent and the coefficient of relative risk aversion

Tags: microeconomics, uncertainty

That's my question!

Propositon 6.C.4 (MWG (1995)): The following conditions for a Bernoulli utility function $u(\cdot)$ on amounts of money are equivalent:

(i) $r_R(x,u)$ is decreasing in $x$.

(iii) Given any risk $F(t)$ on $t>0$, the certainty equivalent $\bar{c_x}$ defined by $u(\bar{c_x})=\int_{}^{} u(tx) \,dF(t)$ is such that $x/\bar{c_x}$ is decreasing in $x$.

Where $r_R(x,u)$ is the coefficient of relative risk aversion at $x$.

If both functions are decreasing in $x$, can we say that one is decreasing in relation to the other? In other words, can we say that the certainty equivalent is decreasing in the coefficient of relative risk aversion?

Thanks!

Comment: The certainty equivalent at some fixed $x$ is a measure of local risk aversion, and so is the coefficient of relative risk aversion. They have to move in the same direction, so the former cannot decrease in the latter. Or did you mean to ask whether $x/\bar{c_x}$ (as opposed to $\bar{c_x}$ itself) is decreasing in the coefficient?